# Parsing JSON with jq

Tags: shell, jq

I have to parse a JSON which includes an array of of class/name:

```
{

    "_class": "model.ListView",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "_class": "hudson.matrix.MatrixProject",
            "name": "tests-different-node-full"
        },
        {
            "_class": "hudson.matrix.MatrixProject",
            "name": "tests-jms-activemq-full"
        },
        {
            "_class": "hudson.matrix.MatrixProject",
            "name": "tests-txpropag-jpa-full"
        }
    ]

}
```

I need to retrieve the list of "name".
Looking at the examples I've found of jq, I have tried with:

```
cat jobs.json | jq '.[].name'
```

It fails with:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with string "name"
```

How should I reference the name element of the array?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
cat jobs.json | jq '.jobs[].name'
```